# Getting number of duplicate elements in a list (in tcl)

Tags: tcl

I have a list which looks like

```
list = {ab bc 8 ab d1 10 xy uv bc ab xy 10 d1}
```

I would like to know how often each element of the list occurs inside it, that is, I need a result like this:

```
ab 3

bc 2

8  1

d1 2

....
```

I prefer a single line argument (if such exists) instead of a proc. I need to work with both: list elements and their frequency in the list.

Any advice is welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `counter` is the name of the dictionary where you want to collect this information (and is either currently unset or set to the empty string):

```
foreach item $list {dict incr counter $item}
```

You can then print that out in approximately the form you gave with:

```
dict for {item count} $counter {puts [format "%6s %-3d" $item $count]}
```

Note that this second line is about *displaying* the data, not actually finding it out.

Comment: You could use an array instead of a dict, but then the order of the elements would be "arbitrary" (technically not random, but extremely hard to predict without a lot of effort as it depends on many details of the array algorithm that aren't documented.)